# How do we identify the C and n0 when proving Big O, Big Omega, and Big Theta?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, bounds

Like the question says, how exactly do we always find the c and n0 for a given bound?

For example, when I had to solve the problem...
Prove that 5n^2+2n+1 = O(n^2)

I was able to look at 2n and say "This can never be greater than 2n^2" and for 1 I was also able to say "This can never be greater than n^2".
By taking this into consideration, I was able to pick C = 8 and n0 = 1.

However, when I'm given a problem such as..
Prove that n^3=O(2^n) using the basic definition of Big O notation.

I have absolutely no clue what to do since the only thing I have to work with is n^3. How do I identify C and n0 for these types of problems?

Comment: I think we have a stack for pure algorithmic question.

Comment: You don't need to find THE C and n0, you just need to find ones that work.

Comment: There is no `n0` for explicit expressions, only recurrence relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find an argument in each specific case, there is no algorithm to find a proof.

In your example we can use that n^3 is even in o(2^n) which clearly implies it is in O(2^n). To see the former, consider the limit for n->infinity of (n^3 / 2^n).
Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) three times, you see the limit is 0.

Comment: To add onto this answer, once you see that the limit tends to 0 you can then just solve for the intercept of these two functions and use that as an n0

Comment: Would C = 1 and n0 = 0 in this case?

Comment: You can set C to 1 (but anything > 0 will work). n0 needs to be larger for C=1: for example n0 = 10 will work. 10^3 = 1000 < 2^10 = 1024. But it is not really important to find a specific value. The fact that the limit goes to 0 guarantees that an n0 exists (this is all we need to know).

Comment: I see, I have a much better understanding now thanks!